# is it possible to connect ac power source to battery in parallel connection ?

Tags: ac, dc, resistance, parallel

Is it possible to connect ac power source & a battery in a parallel connection where a battery is low voltage & have current more then the internal resistance of circuit ?

As the battery is Dc power source but still a conductor so will it pass ac current ? & if yes   can it add some amp in output so that the current can be more than internal resistance of circuit ??

Comment: *"the current can be more than internal resistance of circuit"*!! You can not compare current and resistance.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. You cannot charge a battery this way. You can use a small AC current to measure the internal resistance of a battery (this is one standard way to do it). But the current has to be limited to a reasonable range.

Answer (score 1):

Mixing AC and DC supplies in parallel is similar to adding two different DC sources in parallel, except that one of the sources is constantly pushing and pulling the other supply.  It's probably going to heat something up, *especially* if the AC and DC voltages are not equal.  You can add some extra equipment to isolate them.  There's some discussion about this on [this page](http://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/can-i-use-2-dc-power-supplies-together.27346/) which would be applicable to your proposal.

If the AC voltage is larger than the DC voltage, then it will run your load current in reverse for part of the cycle.  It would probably be best to convert the AC to DC and put in some sort of circuitry to distribute the differences in voltage and protect the supplies.